# What is the difference between Spring CLI and Spring Shell

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-shell, spring-cli

According to my learning, Spring CLI and Spring Shell are tools for building command-line applications, Spring CLI is focused on running Groovy scripts and Spring Boot applications from the command line, whereas Spring Shell provides a framework for building interactive command-line applications with advanced features and extensibility.

What is the difference between Spring Shell and Spring CLI? What are the use cases of both, when to use what?

Answer (score 0):

Spring CLI is used to develop and run Spring applications through the Command Line Interface. You can write Spring applications with simple scripts using the Groovy scripting language. It is especially useful for starting and managing Spring Boot projects.

If your goal is to run and test a spring boot project conveniently and quickly, use spring CLI.
On the other hand, if you want to provide CLI commands to users, you can use spring shell to create CLI commands and provide them to users.